# replace values in dataframe here rowname is equals to column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with binary values. I want to change values to zero where row and column name is same. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
tmp_dict= {'x':[0,0,0,0,0],'y':[1,0,1,0,0],'z':[1,1,1,1,1],'p':[0,1,1,0,1],'q':[0,1,1,1,1]}
mydf= pd.DataFrame(tmp_dict, columns=['x','y','z','p','q'], index=['x','y','z','p','q'])
mydf
   x  y  z  p  q
x  0  1  1  0  0
y  0  0  1  1  1
z  0  1  1  1  1
p  0  0  1  0  1
q  0  0  1  1  1
```

Desired dataframe:

```
   x  y  z  p  q
x  0  1  1  0  0
y  0  0  1  1  1
z  0  1  0  1  1
p  0  0  1  0  1
q  0  0  1  1  0
```

Comment: My actual dataframe does not have row and columns in the same sequence. Alexander's solution works better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the columns and set the corresponding row(s) to zero using `loc`.

```
for col in mydf:
    mydf.loc[col, col] = 0
```